# Bukkit plugin not loading ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm having some issues while trying to load my plugin. I already fixed some of the minor issues but I cannot find a solution for the next error message:

```
    [08:59:47] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\HelloWorld.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `me.CocoArana.005.HelloWorld.Main'
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:66) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:133) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:393) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:301) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:381) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:179) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:786) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:155) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.CocoArana.005.HelloWorld.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:167) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:96) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:64) ~[craftbukkit-1.16.4.jar:git-Bukkit-3eb7236]
        ... 8 more
```

as you can see the error does not point to my code but to the imported library. Already replaced it but still does not work.

Can you please help me?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly specify classpath in Meta-INF. But this is purely minecraft requirements, may be wrong.
I think with this error it is better to go to specialized forums on minecraft, there you will be answered faster and better

Comment: Show us your plugin.yml, and project structure(at least name of package your main class is in).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `plugin.yml` is broken, I suggest to replace the stuff in the line with `main:` in it by the correct path to the main class of your Plugin.

This class also has to extend from `JavaPlugin` to be recognized, so this might also be a reason for this error to appear.